# Mat-button-raised not rendering theme style on angular 7 material

Tags: sass, angular-material, angular7

I cannot get the mat-button-raised button to be styled. I am using angular 7, angular material. No joy.

I tried different imports, using the link tag and importing the theme globally in the .scss file.

```
app.component.html

<mat-toolbar style="display: flex;" role="heading">
  <span style="display: flex;">Music with Angular Components</span>
  <button mat-button-raised color="secondary">Logout</button>
</mat-toolbar>
```

That is the button.

module.ts

```
import { AppRoutingModule } from './app-routing.module';
import { AppComponent } from './app.component';
import { MatButtonModule } from '@angular/material/button';
import { MatCardModule } from '@angular/material/card';
import { MatToolbarModule } from '@angular/material/toolbar';
import { LoginComponent } from './login/login.component';
import { DashboardComponent } from './dashboard/dashboard.component';
import { LandingComponent } from './landing/landing.component';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [
    AppComponent,
    LoginComponent,
    DashboardComponent,
    LandingComponent
  ],
  imports: [
    BrowserModule,
    HttpClientModule,
    AppRoutingModule,
    MatButtonModule,
    MatCardModule,
    MatToolbarModule
  ],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
```

and the global angular style.scss

```
@import '@angular/material/prebuilt-themes/purple-green.css';
```

and finally the angular.json

```
 "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/client",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": [],
            "es5BrowserSupport": true
          },
```

I expect to see styling of the button.

I am stumped. The css style sheet seems to be loading because in the console I can see

```
mat-app-background
```

and the ui reflects it. But no button styling.

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: Try `mat-raised-button`.

Comment: Also, color attribute must be: primary, accent or warn.

Comment: Spot on, thanks for that. Indeed `button` and `raised` were the wrong way round. Thanks @G.Tranter